# Expand Drawing displays behind taskbar in windows 10

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-10

this is work perfectly in win8 and win7. But in win10 it fails.

this.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.SingleBorderWindow;

[the open image displays behind the task bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nL0LB.png)

Comment: Refer this before posting a query on stackoveflow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What fails?   Border unexpected?  Crash?  BSOD?   Internet disconnects?